# What is the best way to put a ListView inside HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: java, android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to make a calendar app and will like to list all the events of a day on a ListView and scroll horizontally the days. When I scroll to the right, ListView should redraw the events for tomorrow. I have all my events in a sqllite database.

This is how my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       

<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

How can I populate the ListView and make it get the new data every time I scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong approach, a ListView can't be nested inside a ScrollView. Use a ViewPager to page the days.

Comment: The author asked about a HorizontalScrollView, since the scrolling axes are perpendicular there is no conflict.

Comment: It is a generally system design you can't use a ListView inside a ScrollView, it doesn't matter if it's a HorizontalScrollView since it derives from the ScrollView class

Comment: Agree with the OP. In theory you could override onInterceptTouchEvent to force the HorizontScrollView to only process horizontal scroll gestures (assuming HorizontalScrollView doesn't do this already). But ViewPager does the right thing out of the box, and provides other benefits as well (such as clamped scrolling).

Comment: If you want to use the idea mentioned in the comment above I would recommend the GestureDetector

Comment: A [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) is not derived from a ScrollView. (I should say I agree that the question's author shouldn't use a HSV, but "can't" is inaccurate.)

Comment: Yeah sorry you are right, but the problem is the same the scroll-event will only be recognized by one element in this case the parent object (the HorizontalScrollView),therfore the touch event will be recognized only for the ScrollView and not for the ListView

Comment: I see, ViewPager is a better choice. I'm trying to develop an app on API level 7/8. I will use ViewPager from the "Android Support Library".

Comment: If you want to develop on API level 7 or 8 use ActionBarSherlock: http://actionbarsherlock.com/ otherwise you will get trouble

Answer (score 0):

I have used a ListView inside a HorizontalScrollView in API 15 and 18.  Both views seem to recognize their required gesture, so it works.  One thing I noticed however is that the width of the ListView is only as wide as the first row in the list.  If subsequent rows are wider the "extra" (length in excess of row 1) won't be visible, but then you can scroll over to see the remaining text, etc...  I haven't noticed any other ill effects.